# create inherit override odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to perform override with odoo 10, the truth is that I want to add functionality to an existing method of odoo and I do not know how to do it, I have already added what I have advanced but the behavior is not appropriate

**original method of validate bottom of odoo :**

```
@api.multi
def action_invoice_open(self):
    # lots of duplicate calls to action_invoice_open, so we remove those already open
    to_open_invoices = self.filtered(lambda inv: inv.state != 'open')
    if to_open_invoices.filtered(lambda inv: inv.state not in ['proforma2', 'draft']):
        raise UserError(_("Invoice must be in draft or Pro-forma state in order to validate it."))
    to_open_invoices.action_date_assign()
    to_open_invoices.action_move_create()
    return to_open_invoices.invoice_validate()
```

I want to add this code to this function:

```
print('enter')
        Replique = self.env['dues.replique'] 
            new = Replique.create({
                    're_customer': self.partner_id.id,
                    'amount_invoice':self.amount_total,
                    'amount_total':self.t_invoice_amount,
                    'n_invoice' : self.number,
                })
```

and I've done it like this:

```
class AddFields(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    @api.model
    def action_invoice_open(self):
        print('enter')
        Replique = self.env['dues.replique'] 
            new = Replique.create({
                    're_customer': self.partner_id.id,
                    'amount_invoice':self.amount_total,
                    'amount_total':self.t_invoice_amount,
                    'n_invoice' : self.number,
                })
        campus_write = super(AddFields,self).action_invoice_open()
        return campus_write
```

but the error is that now only the new code that I have added is executed and the code of the original method is not executed, I do not know how to edit the method instead of canceling it completely.

Comment: use super(ClassName,self).function_name(). If u want to add ur code after main code then place "super" at top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not that bad ;-)

The origin method uses `api.multi` as decorator, don't change that with your extension. `api.model` will make it a non instance/recordset method, so the super call will be done with an empty recordset, which will lead to nothing validated.

Plus: your extension would only work if one single invoice will be validated. But what happens with more than one invoice? It will raise an "expected singleton" error, because `self` won't be a `Singleton`.

So just change it to a loop:

```py
@api.multi  # don't change it to another decorator
def action_invoice_open(self):
    Replique = self.env['dues.replique']
    for invoice in self:
        Replique.create({
            're_customer': invoice.partner_id.id,
            'amount_invoice':invoice.amount_total,
            'amount_total':invoice.t_invoice_amount,
            'n_invoice' : invoice.number,
        })
    result = super(AddFields, self).action_invoice_open()
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend, this is the solution.